# Form not being submitted after processing click event for submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

The button is disabled after the click and the text changes, but the form is not submitted. Any ideas why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pick-button').click(function(){
      $(".pick-button").prop("disabled", true);
      $(".pick-button").prop("value", "PROCESSING. Please wait up to 10 seconds.");
      return true;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: You are interfering with the click event before the default action it leads to (submitting the form) is carried out. A disabled submit button can not submit the form any more. So by the time (after your `return true`) the browser goes, _“hey, what was the default action I was supposed to be carrying out here?”_, it then realizes, _“hey, nothin’ to do here, this thing’s disabled …”_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it seems like you're trying to do something on a form's submit button being clicked, and then submit it. First, give your form an `id` if it doesn't already have one:

```
<form action="www.example.com" id="my-form">
    ...
</form>
```

Then add a `$("#<form-id>").submit();` call to your JavaScript after your attribute changes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pick-button').click(function(){
      $(".pick-button").prop("disabled", true);
      $(".pick-button").prop("value", "PROCESSING. Please wait up to 10 seconds.");
      $("#my-form").submit(); # New function call
      return true;
    });
  });
```

This will force jQuery to submit your form.